# Invoking application programmatically by text gesture on lock screen - iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

How can i place my application icon on the lock screen of the iphone programmatically(something like the default camera button next to slide lock). Is it possible ? If so can any one guide me on this ??

***EDITED***

Hi all.. thanks for replies.. after seeing your replies i understand that this is not possible and its possible in jailbroken devices.. or is it possible to invoke my application through some gesture on lock screen ???

Comment: It's not possible with non jailbroken devices. Neither through a gesture nor by placing a icon on the lock screen. The 3 ways to get started are a click on the app icon, a click on a notification or, if the user selected the open with dialog, via an url scheme

Answer (score 1):

**For Jail broken Device:**

I'm not sure whether it work or not.

Please check these links:

1. [You Tube 1](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC8QtwIwAA&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tOj7dHHLhVk&ei=div-UMTDAcnUrQfD24GwAw&usg=AFQjCNENzxqEDW_RJaSjitGko76GiC_o-Q&sig2=K4_2XVYG2kgl67en74B4-w&bvm=bv.41248874,d.bmk&cad=rja)
2. [You Tube 2](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CDUQtwIwAg&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4rtFExAv9yc&ei=div-UMTDAcnUrQfD24GwAw&usg=AFQjCNHFW_kH_qhqq97FLYahg-WutllNwg&sig2=dbkh-ZSXubrmTsa3mMXMGw&bvm=bv.41248874,d.bmk)

Note : Possibly it is for Jailbroken devices. Also I didn't checked these video's because it's restricted in our company :(

Comment: this app is not available on the appstore so I believe this is for Jailbroken devices...

Answer (score 1):

I dont think it is possible. I understand you want to implement something like android interface, but apple has its UI standards and has restricted access to that.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as Apple does not allow that.